# in visual c++, warning comes but program doesnt runs furthers, is there any way to igonre it?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-c++-2008

I have written some code, here is a snippet of it is:

```
int num[8],n=0;
for (n = 0; n<8; n++)
{
    char temp = binnum[n];
    num[n] = atoi(&temp);
    cout << num[n];
}
```

It doesn't gives any error, but I do get a warning.  When I run it on C++, it gives `Run Time Check Failure - The variable n is being used without being initialized`.
After that, it doesn't run any further and the program closes.  Is there any way to ignore this error?  Because if I initialize `n`, it gives the wrong answer. For example, if answer is 101011, it will give 10101100, which is wrong.

Comment: Two wrongs don't make a right.  You *have* to initialize n, 0 is a logical choice.  Next figure out to what value it should increment, 8 isn't likely to be correct if you are not happy with a result that has 8 digits.

Comment: That code will either crash, do nothing, or loop infinitely, since `n` is never incremented.  Therefore, your problem is with some other piece of code, or version of the code.  Cut and paste the relevant sections of the code you're using.  Also, list the warning rather than just saying there was one.

Comment: You *can*, but it won't give the right result and propably even crash. If it should happen to seem to work, it's a mistake. The code wouldn't compile if C adn C++ weren't so suicidally permissive in this area.

Comment: @delnan:  Are you suggesting variables should be required to be initialized, and that be enforced by static analysis?  That conflicts with the idea that variables should be initialized to meaningful values (since it's not possible to tell whether all actually possible execution paths include initialization), and will result in arbitrary initialization to shut the compiler up.

Comment: @David: Given that today's (C/C++) compilers are already very clever beasts and do perform extensive static analysis (after all, they do warn about uninitialized variables, right?), it doesn't seem too hard. But simply choosing a predictable default value for each type (`0` for numerical types, `NULL` for pointers -- as with default constructors for stack-allocated classes) would help a lot.

Comment: @delnan This is akin to saying C++ should have automatic garbage collection because it's convenient and other languages do it. Other languages do many things that doesn't necessarily mean C++ should.

Comment: @AJG85: Lack of GC is useful in specific areas. Invoking UB is not. Preventing unintialized values seems possible and with zero drawback, care to name any?

Comment: @delnan:  In fact, this is already possible within the Standard, since 8.5/9 specifies an indeterminate value.  This could be a zero-initialization for all the Standard says.  However, a predictable default value doesn't eliminate bugs that arise from bad initialization, since that's not necessarily the right value, and can help cover them up.  I'd rather have some random crashes in testing than have everything look superficially correct.

Comment: @David: Predictable as in "carved in stone for all implementations", not as in "implementation is free to put some value there". And yes, it doesn't magically make all code right (but it shouldn't cause subtle bugs either), but it avoids undefined behaviour (i.e. you can omit the explicit initialization if the default value is what you need). But as I said, I'd prefer static analysis checking for explicit initialization anyway.

Comment: @delan potentially hiding variables by initializing them to non-meaningful values is a drawback. I'd rather have a warning or compile error and then correct the code over unintentional default behavior which causes more subtle bugs elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

**Initialize n** as @anthares pointed out **and increment it** at the end of the loop so your loop actually works.

```
int number[8];
int n = 0;
do
{
    char temp = binnum[n];
    number[n] = atoi(&temp);
    cout << number[n];
    n++;
} while (n<8);
```

Comment: I have understood this, but the problem is, if i give n a value, i.e initialize it with 0, it will give me wrong answer. For example, i want answer as 101011 and it gives me 10101100, which is wrong, considering they are binary nummbers. how to solve this? –

Comment: @bijlikamasla 1 byte has 8 bits, so it seems that 10101100 is the right answer, isn't it? Give me an example, which number are you trying to convert to binary?

Comment: @bijlikamasla I believe you did, and I also believe that this question has been solved by us.

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem (after all the edits) is that `atoi` takes a null-terminated char array (C-style string). The address of a single char variable does not make a C-style string.

To convert a single character in range ['0'...'9'] to a corresponding number use:

```
number[i] = temp - '0';
```

possibly having checked that temp contains a digit character.

Answer (score 0):

Give a value to your vairable n before using it `int number [8], n=0` for example. Otherwise, it is "not defined behavior" what is the value of n and how many iterations you will do in your cycle.

Also, As it is written your loop will go forever since you never change the value of n ...

Comment: if i give n a value, i.e initialize it with 0, it will give me wrong answer. For example, i want answer as 101011 and it gives me 10101100, which is wrong, considering they are binary nummbers. how to solve this?

Comment: You need to give n a value in order to properly access the binnum array. If you think 101011 is the correct answer then you should get only the first six integers from this array. Maybe you should clarify How do you know that only the first six ints matters ?

Comment: no, the thing is, some of the time there are 8 bits, some time 7, some time 6 and so on, it depends upon binnum[i]. I want it to show only that number of bits, no more than that.

Comment: You have to keep somewhere When you have 8 7 or 6 bits and iterate to this number of bits. But not initiating your variable will definitely not solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

You are using n before it is assigned a value. You need to ensure that n is initialized (to 0, maybe) before you begin to reference it in your code. You do not want to ignore this error.

Try something like this:

```
const int count = 8;
int number[count];
    for (int i=0; i < count; i++)
    {
        char temp = binnum[i];
        number[i] = atoi(&temp);
        cout << number[i];
    }
```

Comment: if i give n a value, i.e initialize it with 0, it will give me wrong answer. For example, i want answer as 101011 and it gives me 10101100, which is wrong, considering they are binary nummbers. how to solve this?

Comment: @bijlikamasla: That's a different question.

Answer (score 0):

what? you never assign any value to `n`.
and even if you will for example do `int number[8],n=0;` you never change `n`'s value you you will end up with an infinite loop.

Comment: if i give n a value, i.e initialize it with 0, it will give me wrong answer. For example, i want answer as 101011 and it gives me 10101100, which is wrong, considering they are binary nummbers. how to solve this?

Comment: It doesn't give you 10101100 because you never increment `n`.

Answer (score 0):

You should *really* initialize n (and also increment it, for that matter).
You are probably running a debug build of your application. In this case, the variable is probably always initialized with the same value. This is why you see the result you expect. It **seems** to behave correct **purely by accident.**
As soon as your application is built in release mode, `n` may have a **different value each time the program is run** and thus the output will be unpredictable. 
This is what happens when you have undefined behavior in your program.